# LEFT JOIN WHERE not returning results

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables with columns and I'm doing a basic LEFT JOIN:

### Case 1

```
SELECT g_users.id, g_users.username, f_list.user_id
FROM g_users

LEFT JOIN f_list 
    ON f_list.friend_id = g_users.id 

WHERE g_users.username IN ('meme', 'john', 'doe')
    AND g_users.id != 4
```

Result:
[image]

All good!

### Case 2, applied on same records

```
SELECT g_users.id, g_users.username, f_list.user_id
FROM g_users

LEFT JOIN f_list ON 
    f_list.friend_id = g_users.id 

WHERE g_users.username IN ('meme', 'john', 'doe')
    AND g_users.id != 4
    AND f_list.user_id != 4
```

Result:
[image]

I was expecting to return doe's records but it returned nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Your use of `GROUP BY` is invalid.  The `SELECT `list has columns that are inconsistent with the `GROUP BY` -- those from the `f_list` table.

Comment: Don't use `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *`. Such a query makes no sense and fails anywhere but MySQL (may be allowed in SQLite). Apologies you had to learn SQL this way!

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've removed group by. It still doesn't work. I've updated the question.

Comment: If you NEVER use `SELECT *`, you probably won't go too far wrong.

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE` (with conditions using left joined table) = `INNER JOIN`. Quite a while ago, `WHERE` was used for the implicit join!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the wonderful world of NULL handling.

The problem arises when doing a comparison in your WHERE clause with the table you're left joining to. You have that f_list.user_id != 4. For the rows that don't have a match with your left join, this expression is evaluating if *null* != 4, which is false because it's a null value.

You have 2 unique matched values, *null* and 4, of which both get excluded in the above statement, which leaves you with 0 rows as a result.

To get your desired outcome, you can wrap f_list.user_id in a null handling function, such as COALESCE.

Comment: COALESCE wouldn't work in this scenario as it would still return a null for this condition

Comment: It's implied that you would need to provide at least 2 arguments, such as COALESCE(user_id, -1).

Answer (score 0):

If you have **ANSI_NULLS ON** a comparison condition containing a **NULL** value returns unknown rather than true or false. Your condition AND f_list.user_id != 4 isn't returning true for doe's row

You can try to run

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

before your query or escape NULLS

[ANSI_NULLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**EDIT**
As the user explained it's a Mariadb the only option available is escaping nulls using
AND (f_list.user_id != 4 or AND f_list.user_id IS NULL)

Comment: I'm using MariaDB not MSSQL. I can't turn it off

Comment: Apologies, I haven't noticed the dbms you're using. You'd need to do a null safe comparison or manually add "or f_list.user_id is null".

Comment: My pleasure! :)